# Return object value from Firebase realtime DataBase

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire, angularfire2

i have a list of objects (users) in Firebase. 
Every object looks like this: 
[image]

And i want get 'banned' value for user.

Now my func looks like this:

```
  isBanned() {
    return this.db.object(`users/${this.authState.uid}/banned`)
  }
```

and it's return nothing. How should i write this correctly?

I'm using angular 5 and AngularFire2.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible your `.onAuthStateChanged`asynch method has not resolved when this function gets fired. Try and see by console'ing out the `${this.authState.uid}` from within that function. If it's `null` that's your issue (asnych issue)

Assuming you do have the `uid`, try and just get the whole parent node then `snap.val().banned`.

Answer (score 1):

The core of the problem is that authState is async. I'd recommend you rewrite this as an Observable mapped from AngularFireAuth's authState:

```
this.isBanned$ = this.afAuth.authState.switchMap(u => u ? this.db.object(`users/${u.id}/banned`).valueChanges() : Observable.of(undefined))
```